# Freemarker regular expression not working for groups?

Tags: freemarker

I have a working reg ex -> https://regex101.com/r/aX0xL6/3

that basically converts input->output

INPUT:

```
**1** Blah  **3** Blah **I am * all bold**
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
<b>1</b> Blah  <b>3</b> Blah <b>I am * all bold</b>
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work for freemarker?

```
${stringStuff?replace("\*{2}(.+?)\*{2}\", "<b>$1</b>", "r")}
```

> see link for working example and details for basic regex match and replace
>
> https://regex101.com/r/aX0xL6/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked!

```
<#if lineItem?has_content>${stringStuff?replace("\\*{2}(.+?)\\*{2}", "<b>$1</b>", "r")}</#if>
```

Comment: Note that you don't need all those \\-s (double backslashes), if you start the string literal like `r"..."`. So the it would be `r"\*{2}(.+?)\*{2}"`. (BTW `r` stands for "raw", not "regular expression".)